# Check if Class<T> is primitive and if its String, Number, Boolean, List or Map?

Tags: java

I have this code that I am having trouble with:

```
public static <T> T createPOJOFrom(Class<T> clazz, Entity source){
    T obj = null;
    if (clazz.isPrimitive()){
        Map<String,Object> props = source.getProperties();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> it = props.entrySet().iterator();
        Object prop = it.next();
        obj = (T) prop; // FIXME this can be dangerous!
    } else {
        obj = createPOJOFrom(clazz, createMapFromEntity(source));
    }
    return obj;
}
```

**Question 1:**

The problem is `clazz.isPrimitive` returns `false` because I can see in the debug console that `clazz = class java.lang.String`, now how  do I also do a check for `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `List` and `Map`?

What could be wrong in this code?

**Question 2:**

If ever question 1 is fixed, what is the safest way to assign `Object prop` to `T`, example if `T` is a `String`, then it would be `String.valueOf` right? What if its primitive like `int`, `long`, `char`?

Comment: String, Number, Boolean, List and Map are not primitives, they all classes.  `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `float`, `double`, `long` are all primitives.

Comment: `if(String.class == clazz)` will tell you if clazz is String class.

Comment: `prop` is a `Map.Entry`, which is basically a pair of things - a key and a value.  Are you after the key or the value here?  Please clarify.

Comment: Also, I see a `StackOverflowError` in your near future.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, you should avoid `obj = (T) prop;`.

Comment: If you wanna check what type it is, use the instanceof keyword. `if(prop instanceof String)` if your goal is to check what the object is

Comment: @PeterLawrey `List` and `Map` aren't classes.

Comment: @VinceEmigh When I debug the prop class is class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntry

Comment: @xybrek Do you mind adding the resources to run this in your question? `Entity` and `createMapFromEntity(Entity)`. It would be easier to help if I could run it, and see the rest of the context. Also, are you looking to iterate through the values of the map only? Or do you wanna return the entire entry (key AND value) instead of just the value?

Comment: @VinceEmigh actually you can get all the codes here: http://git.io/p3z3CA (it's open source) triggered on the KeyValueStoreLongTest class there.

Comment: @DavidWallace I meant any implementation of those will be classes. BTW You have `Class c = Map.class;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final look:

```
public static <T> T createObjectFrom(Class<T> clazz, Entity source){
    T obj = null;
    Map<String,Object> props = source.getProperties();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> it = props.entrySet().iterator();
    if (props.size() > 1){
        if (clazz == List.class){
            throw new RuntimeException("Not yet implemented");
        } else if (clazz == Map.class){
            throw new RuntimeException("Not yet implemented");
        } else {
            obj = createPOJOFrom(clazz, createMapFromEntity(source));
        }
    } else if (props.size() == 1) {
        Map.Entry<String,Object> entry = it.next();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (clazz.isPrimitive()){
            obj = (T) value;
        } else if (clazz == String.class){
            String prop = String.valueOf(value);
            obj = (T) prop;
        } else if (clazz == Number.class || clazz == Long.class || clazz == Integer.class){
            Long prop = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(value));
            obj = (T) prop;
        } else if (clazz == Boolean.class){
            Boolean prop = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(value));
            obj = (T) prop;
        }
    } else {
        // empty
    }
    return obj;
}
```